# How to implement database search in an app where search is the main focus?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm developing an app that calls a database via REST API from a main view and returns results in JSON format, to be parsed and displayed on a new view likely in ListView format. From the results list view, users can click on a specific result and see a "place view" with information specific to that place. The originally returned JSON objects that populated ListView will likely be used to populate the place page. I've been doing a lot of research about how best to implement this, and there doesn't seem to be any right answer or consensus. A few of my questions:

1. Should the main search and results listview be one activity? If they are, it seems like I can use AsyncTask to make the search to
   the external database. Is that a good use of AsyncTask?
2. If main search and results are separate activities, can I still use AsyncTask, or do I have to get more complex and use a Service to
   make that call? I've gotten the idea in my head that AsyncTask only
   can be used within an activity, and not to take a search term from
   one activity and return results to another. Can someone clarify that
   for me?
3. Is there a single proper way to implement this type of very common search?
4. Can anyone point me to sample code that illustrates a similar search and response being done? I have sample code and understanding
   of creating the actual REST methods, but I'd love to see some code
   that shows a search structure like mine (rest api, input and results
   in different views, etc) being implemented properly.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to develop an app with very similar functions as the one that you are working on. Here are some ideas of what I would do in your situation:

1. Should the main search and results listview be one activity? I would say no, its better to separate the the main search into separate activities.
2. If main search and results are separate activities, can I still use AsyncTask? I used the IntenetService ResultReceiver pattern. I found that once I had set it up, it was very easy to adapt to any rest calls. Here is the link that I used to learn how to use it. [Modern Techniques for implementing Rest clients](http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/01/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks, would you mind letting me see your code?  Or is your code more or less modeled after what is in the linked tutorial?

Comment: Its pretty much like the tutorial - thats why I didn't past any code. If there is a specific area that you could use some more detail let me know.